# date formula to return blank if cell is empty

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula in cell R3. =If(Isblank(E3),"",(E3)+365. This formula gives me the date I am looking for if I have a date entered in cell E3. However cell E3 does not always have a date in it. When there is no date in cell E3 I get #Value in cell R3. Is there a way to leave R3 blank if no date entered in E3.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=IF(E3="","",E3+365)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you could wrap your entire formula within an `IFERROR()` function:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(E3), "", E3+365), "")
```

The advantage of this (or disadvantage depending on which way you look at it) is that it will also mitigate any other errors you might encounter from incorrect data types being placed into cell E3, such as `#DIV/0`, etc.